# Can't compile OSL

Tags: compiler-errors, codeblocks

I've been using blender for years and recently got a college project on OSL (Open Shading Language). I've downloaded the osl source code from GitHub. I also have all dependencies for building osl.

I'm trying to use code::blocks ide with mingw32 (on windows) to compile it. I have a problem when I go to build any program of the project including:

1. The OSL compiler
2. The OSL executer (interpreter)
3. TestShade
4. TestRender

Every time, I face many compilation errors. I know that the code I've downloaded have no errors in it. So I'm sure there's problem with my compiler.

Can anyone suggest me a compiler and IDE (please, don't suggest Visual Studio) for a successful build of osl? I'll also be happy if someone build me all the osl programs listed above (for Windows).

Comment: Probably there is nothing wrong with your compiler, either, other than it being hard to use. I imagine that you are having trouble running `make` or `configure`?

Comment: If you share the exact steps you follow in order to compile OSL, someone might be able to catch your mistake. Or, give you direction.